# How to Automatically Add STRUCT Elements in BigQuery

Tags: google-bigquery

I have a BigQuery table with a STRUCT field and I would like to be able to automatically increase its list of elements whenever I attempt to insert a previously unseen element. Is this possible?

```sql
-- initially meta only has elements: hair, eyes
CREATE TEMP TABLE tt AS
SELECT
  1 AS id,
  STRUCT (
    'brown' AS hair,
    'brown' AS eyes
  ) AS meta;

-- now I would like to add a neverbefore seen element: weight
INSERT INTO tt
SELECT
  2 AS id,
  STRUCT (
    'brown' AS hair,
    160 AS weight
  ) AS meta;
```

This obviously does not work and returns the error `Query column 2 has type STRUCT<hair STRING, weight INT64> which cannot be inserted into column meta, which has type STRUCT<hair STRING, eyes STRING> at [10:1]`.

The resulting temp table looks like the following after the initial construction:

| id | meta.hair | meta.eyes |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | brown | brown |

And then it would ideally automatically add the element "weight" to meta after inserting row 2:

| id | meta.hair | meta.eyes | meta.weight |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | brown | brown | NULL |
| 2 | brown | NULL | 160 |

This is probably wishful thinking.

As a real-world example, I know that [Stitch](https://www.stitchdata.com/)'s [Webhook](https://www.stitchdata.com/docs/integrations/webhooks/stitch-incoming-webhooks) --> BigQuery integration is somehow achieving this behavior when it syncs data from some of our SaaS products into BigQuery. Stitch handles new, never-seen-before nested fields inside JSON payloads by adding new elements to corresponding STRUCT fields. I am just not sure how this magic is happening.

Comment: please provide examples of initial data and expected output. most important here is `expected output` as this will drive the solution

Comment: But to make it simple - I would recommend just using json here instead of struct, so you will not be bound by struct schema

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming your have two sets of data

table_1
[image]

and table_2
[image]

Consider below approach

```
create temp function json_extract_keys(input string) returns array<string> language js as """
  return Object.keys(JSON.parse(input));
  """;
create temp function json_extract_values(input string) returns array<string> language js as """
  return Object.values(JSON.parse(input));
  """;

create temp table temp_table as (
  select id, key, value
  from (
    select id, to_json_string(meta) json from table_1 
    union all
    select id, to_json_string(meta) from table_2 
  ), unnest(json_extract_keys(json)) key with offset
  join unnest(json_extract_values(json)) value with offset
  using(offset)
  );

execute immediate(select '''
select id, struct(''' || string_agg(distinct key, ',') || ''') meta from temp_table
pivot (any_value(value) for key in ("''' || string_agg(distinct key, '","') || '"))'
from temp_table
);
```

with output

[image]

Comment: As usual, I am left blown away after reading your suggested answer. I still haven't broken down each step to fully comprehend how this is working, but it does work as advertised. Also, your comment on my original question -- that I should consider simply using a JSON field type -- was very helpful and what I ultimately did for the challenge that I faced this weekend. I will continue exploring this helpful answer to think about how I want to solve this sort of problem in the future.

Answer (score 2):

One way of doing this is with key-value fields in an array. Instead of naming the fields directly, you add a *name* field and a field for each data type you need:

```sql
CREATE TEMP TABLE tt AS
SELECT
    1 AS id,
    [
      STRUCT('hair' as name, 'brown' AS str_value, null as int_value),
      STRUCT('eyes' as name, 'brown' AS str_value, null as int_value)
    ] AS meta;

INSERT INTO tt
SELECT
    2 AS id,
    [
      STRUCT('hair' as name, 'brown' AS str_value, null as int_value),
      STRUCT('weight' as name, cast(null as string) AS str_value, 160 as int_value)
    ] AS meta;

select * from tt
```

Note, that the default data type is int64 (in case you're not explicit using *null*)